# SpringBoot 1.2 throws NoClassDefFoundError on shutdown

Tags: java, spring, jetty, spring-boot

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/FutureCallback
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.shutdown(AbstractConnector.java:285)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.shutdown(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.shutdown(ServerConnector.java:341)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStop(Server.java:404)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.stop(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:149)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.stopAndReleaseEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:277)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:142)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:804)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.FutureCallback
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:170)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:136)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52)
        at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:124)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:444)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        ... 16 more
```

Dependencies:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

It also happened with 1.1.3 and 1.1.4, same error.

If its not clear from the POM I'm using the embedded jetty9 server.  Also using Java7. The error appears when I ctr-c the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines ...

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
```

... means you have a bad jar file.

Now, to be clear, this only means your JAR file is bad at the point in time when the `org.eclipse.jetty.util.FutureCallback` class is being loaded by Spring Boot.

The origin of this bad jar file could be from the beginning (such as having a bad copy in your local maven repository) or during runtime (commonly seen as a secondary process that messes around with your live runtime jars and classes).

As for fixing this, I would start with analyzing the jar files you use (try unpacking them entirely into a temp directory).  Maybe even forcing a a fresh download of the jars in the local repository directory (maybe even look into [`dependency:purge-local-repository`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html) maven plugin goal for details)

Comment: Yeah, that was it, the Jetty jar itself was bad.  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, the corruption keeps coming back after a few compiles.  I suspect it might be because my local repository is on an NFS mount.

Comment: Problem ended up being that one of the build scripts was overwriting the jar file being used by the users local development server.  So, unlike using a J2EE container where you can just overwrite the .war file, you must first shutdown the server then overwrite the jar or else you will not get a clean shutdown.  This is due to the fact that a J2EE container will usually unzip the war into a temporary area and use that vs running off the war directly.  So in this case I was clobbering a file that the server had open.